# running two commands from a single terminal

Tags: command-line

I want to run 2 commands from a single terminal

```
apt-get update && dpkg -L
```

not like that, I want to be able to enter one command that executes the same time as the second command in a second terminal

that might sound confusing, let me try another way

I want to be able to run for example:

```
firefox && apt-get upgrade
```

and have two different terminals open automatically and execute both of those commands just by running a terminal command, not a script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could type these commands after the `$` prompt:

```
$ sudo apt update &
[1] 24966

$ firefox

[1]+  Stopped                 sudo apt update
```

The first command followed by `&` tells it to start in a second terminal (background session). The terminal immediately displays the process ID (`24966`) of the background session and prompts for another command. When the first command finishes you are notified in the terminal by:

```
[1]+  Stopped                 sudo apt update
```

Comment: no no no, i want two terminals to open by running one command, both terminals execute separate commands from the 1st terminal

Comment: @hellomoto I've linked another question to this one, please see. The basic idea is that you can either run `gnome-terminal -e "command"` or open one window with multiple tabs each having its own command

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy "linked" or "hammered" ;)

Comment: So long as it helps, either linking or hammering work :)

Comment: Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.
Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.